# Wireshark can't open .cap captured by iptrace -T

Tags: macos, wireshark

The .cap file is captured on AIX v7.1 by iptrace -a -T -b -d XXX.XXX.XX.XXX mycap.cap

when I try to open it with wireshark/tshark on MAC OSX, it shows:

The capture file appears to be damaged or corrupt. (pcap: File has 3130924352-byte packet, bigger than maximum of 262144)

I think it's iptrace's problem. as this is given once I try it with tcpdump -r:

SONGMBP:toibm6 song$ tcpdump -r bk22.cap
reading from file bk22.cap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
-5:-46:-20.131076 [|ether]
tcpdump: pcap_loop: bogus savefile header
SONGMBP:toibm6 song$

my tcpdump version is shipped with MAC OS X.

So why ? thanks in advance.

Comment: "pcap: File has 3130924352-byte packet" does not appear as a `wireshark` using the `iptrace` parser.  The `File > Open` menu in wireshark has an option in which you can select the type of file being opened.  By default it is set to `Automatic` but you shall set it explicitly to `AIX iptrace`, guessing a file type from its content is not an exact science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the idea. Even ipreport -T on the same host of AIX couldn't parse the data.

Thanksfully newer versions of AIX ships tcpdump with it. So... I'll go for tcpdump instead.